# Como fazer uma TableView Reusavel?

Tags: ios, swift

Em 90% das minhas telas irei precisar de uma tableview para preencher o conteúdo, como posso fazer esta tableview reusável ? digo como posso simplificar a inserção desta table em várias views, meu código é o seguinte:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak
  var tableView: UITableView!

    var textArray: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textArray.addObject("Exemplo1.")

    self.textArray.addObject("Exemplo2.")

    self.textArray.addObject("Exemplo3.")

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }



  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) - > Int {
    return self.textArray.count;
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) - > UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel ? .text = self.textArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as ? String

    return cell

  }


}
```

Fora o trabalho da Main.Storyboard que é colocar uma tableView, colocar o auto-layout inserir o Identifier e colocar o @IBOutlet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi bem a sua questão, porém creio que vc quer ter outra tableview em outra tela do mesmo jeito da primeira, alem de montar ela no storyboard e conectar os outlet's, basta inserir o delegate e data source depois da declaração da classe, criar uma array com os objetos que irão aparecer na table e iniciar no viewDidLoad, e depois setar as funções de numberOfRowsInSection e cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Você entendeu bem a minha questão, eu tenho cerca de 30 viewControllers que precisei preencher cada uma com as mesmas  configurações, queria uma forma de criar uma classe/plugin para tornar esse código mais DRY, digo evitar sempre repetir o mesmo código em várias telas.

Comment: Nesse caso creio eu que vc poderá apenas criar uma classe extension e criar alguma funcão com um init que retorne um array para preencher cada table e só, pois os outlet's tem que ser manuais pois tem que que conectar codigo e view, alem de deixar em conformidade o delegate e o data source com os respectivos códigos.